# Replace all occurrences of scientific numbers with regular numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, math, numbers

I've got a large XML string with decimal values in regular and scientific notation. I need a way to convert all the exponential values to regular notation in-place.

So far I've put together the following Regex which grabs every instance of a exponential number.

```
/-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/
```

And I can convert those to regular notation using:

```
Number('1.255262969126037e-14').toFixed();
```

Now how do I put it all together; **How do I find and replace all occurrences of scientific notation values with regular notation, in-place?**

---

Considering the following input:

> `<path class="arc" d="M1.3807892660386408e-14,-225.50000000000003A225.50000000000003,225.50000000000003 0 0,1 219.47657188958337,51.77146310079094L199.52415626325757,47.06496645526448A205,205 0 0,0 1.255262969126037e-14,-205Z">`

I need the following output:

> `<path class="arc" d="M0,-225.50000000000003A225.50000000000003,225.50000000000003 0 0,1 219.47657188958337,51.77146310079094L199.52415626325757,47.06496645526448A205,205 0 0,0 0,-205Z">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts not only replacement string, but also accepts replacement function:

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the
>   function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The
>   function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string.

To convert all scientific notation values to normal notation:

```
input.replace(/-?\d+(\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, function(match, $1) {

    // Count the number of digits after `.`,
    // then -1 to delete the last digit,
    // allowing the value to be rendered in normal notation
    var prec = $1 ? $1.length - 1 : 0; 

    // Return the number in normal notation
    return Number(match).toFixed(prec);
})
// => <path class="arc" d="M0.0000000000000138,-225.50000000000003A225.50000000000003,225.50000000000003 0 0,1 219.47657188958337,51.77146310079094L199.52415626325757,47.06496645526448A205,20‌​5 0 0,0 0.000000000000013,-205Z">
```

To truncate all floats (scientific or normal) into integers:

```
var input = '<path class="arc" d="M1.3807892660386408e-14,-225.50000000000003A225.50000000000003,225.50000000000003 0 0,1 219.47657188958337,51.77146310079094L199.52415626325757,47.06496645526448A205,205 0 0,0 1.255262969126037e-14,-205Z">';
input.replace(/-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, function(match) {
    return Number(match).toFixed();
})
// => "<path class="arc" d="M0,-226A226,226 0 0,1 219,52L200,47A205,205 0 0,0 0,-205Z">"
```

Comment: That's incorrect somehow. Every single number has become an integer value! I just want the exponential numbers to be converted to floats, preserving the floating point value!!! Can you fix it?

Comment: @Geotarget, How about specifying precision to `toFixed`: `toFixed(13)`?

Comment: Still bad. any other ideas?

Comment: Even `toPrecision(1)` outputs exponent notation : `<path class="arc" d="M1e-14,-2e+2A2e+2,2e+2 0 0,1 2e+2,5e+1L2e+2,5e+1A2e+2,2e+2 0 0,0 1e-14,-2e+2Z">"`

Comment: @Geotarget, How about this? `input.replace(/-?\d+(\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, function(match, $1) {
    var prec = $1 ? $1.length - 1 : 0;
    return Number(match).toFixed(prec);
})`

Comment: Brilliant! It works. Can you add that as the main answer and update the result value to this : `<path class="arc" d="M0.0000000000000138,-225.50000000000003A225.50000000000003,225.50000000000003 0 0,1 219.47657188958337,51.77146310079094L199.52415626325757,47.06496645526448A205,205 0 0,0 0.000000000000013,-205Z">`

Comment: updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for your feedback.